# How to initialize jQuery UI Tabs without using the 'href' attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, tabs

When using a `<base>` tag within a page that renders tabbed content by using the jQuery UI Tabs plugin, all hell breaks lose on that page. That's somehow because of the `href` attribute applied to the tabs' "title" elements, that the plugin relies on. 
From the plugin's documentation:

> Each tab "title" must be inside of a list item (`<li>`) and wrapped by
>   an anchor (`<a>`) with an `href` attribute"

Here's an example from my app:

```
<li><a href="#productsSection"><span>Choose product</span></a></li>
```

Is there a workaround I can use to initialize the Tabs plugin without using the `href` attribute? Off the top of my head, I believe it would have been better to rely on a `data-href` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use following snippet to reconstruct the `href` propety:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").find('a').prop('href', function(){
        return window.location.href + $(this).attr('href');
    }).end().tabs(); // << initialize plugin HERE
});
```

### --See for example--